# CSS styling for specific maximum width at specific maximum aspect ratio

Tags: css

I was trying to style for a screen that is less than 992px and aspect ratio less than 1. Here is what I tried. It is not working. Is it possible to do something like this in CSS? Here is what I tried.

```
@media screen 
  and (max-width: 992px)
  and (max-aspect-ratio: 1){
    .classStyle{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
```

Comment: is my answer is helpful for you or need any assistance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use like this

```
@media (aspect-ratio: 1/1) {
  div {
    background: red;
  }
}
```

Also can learn more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/aspect-ratio)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want..

```
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) and (aspect-ratio: 1/1){
    body{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
```